# Criteria of HTTPS compliance

Tags: https

Recently google announced all website must be HTTPS compliance. I want to know criteria of HTTPS compliance. One criteria is all contents loaded in the website must be loaded through HTTPS connection.

### Question 1

What are the full criteria for HTTPS compliance ?

### Question 2

- If I have some http links in my website (  linktext ) is it HTTPS compliance or non compliance ?
- My website supports HTTPS. But it also works for HTTP. For example
  https://example.com and http://example.com both works. Then is it HTTPS compliance or non compliance.

My assumption is both cases are HTTPS compliance. Could someone clarify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely referring to their Ad Network:

https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6015286?hl=en

This excludes the majority of websites need for SSL compliance. Typically SSL compliance is only required if you are handling personal data. But to answer your second set of questions:

1. Outbound links will not cause an issue with SSL compliance. The only time a URL is subject to those rules is when they are loading a server asset.

   2. You can either set up a redirect in your .htaccess to redirect users to the secure version or set up a canonical URL so that the non secure version doesn't get indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes my website deals with personal data. Thank you for the link. For question 2 there is no direct http:// link from my website. Its always https:// but some user can modify to http:// by firebug or in address bar. In that case for making SSL compliance do I need to redirect http -> https ?

Comment: @MAKRipon you deals with personal data and don't redirect users to your secure version? So you don't protect it. You should redirect http to https, and if possible activate HSTS to prevent SSLStrip attacks.